# Paypal date formatting: what is "HH:MM:SS DD Mmm YY, YYYY PST"?

Tags: time, formatting, paypal

I'm looking at the PayPal `IPN docs`, and it says the `datetime` stamps of their strings are formatted as:

```
HH:MM:SS DD Mmm YY, YYYY PST
```

So year is specified twice?

Once in double digits, and another with 4 digits?

This looks bizarre.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the documentation. The actual format should be "HH:MM:SS Mmm DD, YYYY PST" (e.g. "08:30:06 Apr 19, 2017 PDT")

Comment: +1.  However, the real format still causes problems with common parsing libraries (e.g. http://rhnh.net/2008/03/17/paypal-ipn-fails-date-standards).  ISO 8601 exists for a reason...

Answer (score 4):

Actually in PHP you need to use date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z") . That will result in something that looks like 2012-04-30T00:05:47Z -- I didn't notice a difference between urlencoded and non.

Where are you guys finding this info? This information is elusive in their documentation and cost me an hour or two of hunting and trying stuff. The only place I see this format is in the TIMESTAMP field. Having a hard time with the PayPal NVP API's PROFILESTARTDATE for CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile and a "Subscription start date should be valid" error.

Answer (score 4):

For php, the syntax is `date("G:i:s M m, Y T");`

Comment: The day of the month is `d`, so this should be `G:i:s M d, Y T`.

Answer (score 2):

this is the correct format according to their documentation - 2010-03-27T12:34:49Z
so it is - YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ (I don't know what the T in the middle and Z is but it's constant for all the dates)
I've created PayPal NVP library in Java, so if you want to check how it works, or use it, 
you are more than welcome. it's on sourceforge - payapal-nvp.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a
second
      YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
Where TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)

Example
1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00 corresponds to November 5, 1994, 8:15:30 am, US Eastern Standard Time.

1994-11-05T13:15:30Z corresponds to the same instant.

https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Format to Any format 100% working and easy copy Paste

```
$payPalFormat = "18:30:30 Feb 28, 2008 PST";
$subrotoFormat = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($payPalFormat));
```

Result: 2008-02-29

All Format: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp
https://gist.github.com/subrotoice/d820863ce65eb0d8434a47a76d005df4 (Subroto Biswas Gist)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I think the right format is: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:MM:ssZ

The case is important.

Comment: Must be incorrect, as month and minute have the same case in your example.